# Захват изображения окна приложения

Tags: c#

Есть приложение World Of Warcraft 8)

Пытаюсь получить скриншот окна. Но могу получить только один раз, больше он не обновляется.

```
static IntPtr WindowHandle;

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {

        var title = "Wow";


        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(title);

        if (processes.Length == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Could not find the wow process; is wow running?");
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(processes.Length.ToString());

            WindowHandle = processes [0].MainWindowHandle;

            SetForegroundWindow (WindowHandle);

            Console.WriteLine("Select wow process: " + processes[0].Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Title wow process: " + processes[0].MainWindowTitle);

        }

            int x = 1;
            int y = 1;

            int _x = 1792;
            int _y = 1038;


            Bitmap screenPixel = new Bitmap (_x, _y);

            Graphics gdest = Graphics.FromImage (screenPixel);

            // Проблема
            Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd (WindowHandle);

            IntPtr hsrcdc = gsrc.GetHdc ();
            IntPtr hdc = gdest.GetHdc ();
            BitBlt (hdc, 0, 0, _x, _y, hsrcdc, x, y, (int)CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);


            gdest.ReleaseHdc ();
            gsrc.ReleaseHdc ();

            Console.WriteLine (screenPixel.GetPixel (0, 0).ToString ());
            screenPixel.Save (@"c:\temp\1\test.png");
            }
```

При запуске этого кода, я получаю скриншот окна. Вроде бы все хорошо. Но после того как я перезапускаю этот код, скриншот остается старый... Первый при запуске. Если закрыть Wow и запустить код заново, то скриншот будет новый. Не могли бы помочь в решении данной проблемы?

P.S Если в `Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd (WindowHandle);` поменять на 
`Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd (IntPtr.Zero);` - то он делает скрины без перезапуска процесса wow! но тогда скрин всего рабочего стола, а не приложения отдельно.

Answer (score 1):

так по коду он и должен же 1 раз делать скриншот :)

1. Выведи код делающий скриншот в отдельный метод
2. Добавь цикл который будет делать скниншоты по кругу
3. Добавь Thread.Sleep(1000); в начале цикла (ждать 1 секунду перед тем как делать следующий скриншот)
4. добавь вызов метода делающий скниншот.
5. Так же нужно что бы ты генерил автоматическое имя скриншоту. Бери имена всех файлов в папке, парсь последний файл в инт и таким макаром генери следующее имя.